# Did the Republican and Democratic parties swap ideologies at one point?

Tags: united-states, history, politics

Assuming data like this is correct:

[image]

A common explanation is that the ideologies of these two political parties *switched* at some point in the last 150ish years, and what is the Progressive Democratic party of today would more closely resemble what would have been the "Progressive" yet so-called Republican Party of years past.

**Is there evidence for this alleged switch of party ideologies?**

---

Related: [Are the voting figures correct in this image about historical US decisions by party?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35711/are-the-voting-figures-correct-in-this-image-about-historical-us-decisions-by-pa)

Comment: This should be asked on [politics.se].

Comment: There is a similar (but not identical) question on Politics.SE: [Why have the Democratic Party and Republican Party switched positions on civil rights since the Civil War?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/9783/6511). That said, I think that this question would fit on both that site and this one. After all, there are plenty of politics questions answered on this site.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the "Please Keep Quiet" message in the image is supposed to mean. That we should keep quiet on the fact that the Republican party supported these past issues?

Comment: @Thunderforge I think the "Please Keep Quiet" portion is meant to be sarcastic, telling the viewer that if they don't keep quiet they'll disrupt the supposed rumor that the Republican party is full of racists.

Comment: @Thunderforge I think that it's continuing the header. I understood it as "If you don't know [what good the republican party did in the past for black people] please keep quiet", ie don't criticize what the republican party is doing now, because you don't know the historic background. It's a bit ironic as the graphic itself is missing a lot of historic background.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Politics SE.

Comment: I believe that a large fraction of the US public view the Republican position on these four issues as... "Yes" to basic human rights and "No" to government takeover of health care.  Given that characterization, I think that there is no ideological shift necessary to explain the votes.

Comment: @James The motivations of the parties as they are now is based upon the people that currently make up the party. Since we are talking 146 and more years ago, you really can't attribute current political motivations in any meaningful way.

Comment: Nominated for reopening, see [meta discussion](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3775/republican-democrat-swap-should-be-reopened)

Comment: Is Obamacare the same type of "Progressivism" (which started, realistically, with Wildrow WIlson) as the Abolitionist and Racial Equality movements? Also, don't forgot Eisenhower (R) started a full scale removal of discrimination, especially in government: http://www.ontheissues.org/Celeb/Dwight_Eisenhower_Civil_Rights.htm